# ASP.Net MVC: How to correctly pass in string as data to POST call in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

On my front end, I have a simple button:

```
<input class="btn" value="Something" ng-click="doStuff('myNameisEarl')" />
```

My Angular.js is as follows:

```
$scope.doStuff = function (name) {

    $http.post('/api/callToApi', name)
    .then(function (response) {
        // Do something with response
    }, function () {
        console.log("Failure");
    });
}
```

Then my back end C# Controller is:

```
[HttpPost("api/callToApi")]
public IActionResult Get(string name)
{
    return Ok(_context.MyDBTable.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(name)));
}
```

Unfortunately, when I pass in `name` from my angular code to the C# function, `string name` is `null`.

Why is that? What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting data from body which we normally do, you can explicit say [FromBody] in action method.

```
$scope.doStuff = function (name) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({name: name}); // Convert to a JSON string
    $http.post('/api/callToApi', data)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Success");
    }, function () {
        console.log("Failure");
    });
}

[HttpPost("api/callToApi")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string name)
{
    return Ok(_context.MyDBTable.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(name)));
}
```

***FYI***: You want to name action method as **Post** instead of **Get** for best practice.

Comment: @RamSingh `he is using the POST method, if you check the code carefully.` My answer is also about the Post. I'm not really understanding your comment. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: FYI: You want to name action method as Post instead of Get for best practice

you added this line so i added my comment. skip if you were trying to add more info. i am going to delete it in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can send the name in the querystring. the querystring key should match with the parameter name.

This should work.

```
$scope.doStuff = function (name) {

    $http.post('/api/callToApi?name='+ name )
    .then(function (response) {

           var responseData = response.data;
           console.log(responseData);

        }, function () {
        console.log("Failure");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve the problem

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/controller/action',
        type: "POST",
        data: {name: variable}
    }).done((data) => {
        successCallBack(data);
    }).fail((response) => {
        failureCallBack(response);
    });
```

This should work.